# Changing the value of a property of another UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new to iOS development and I am a little stumped. It would be great if someone could help me out.

I have one UIViewController with a bunch of buttons. These buttons are supposed to set a value for a second UIViewcontroller, depending on which you press. For example, the second UIViewController has a property like an NSString. When I push a button in the first view controller (let's say "Banana"), I want the NSString of the second UIViewController to have "Banana" assigned to it. Or when I push the button called Apple, the NSString is now assigned "Apple".

In the UI, the user will visit the first controller to select the button and then later on, visit the second controller, which will already have the value the user pressed from the first controller, ready to manipulate. The two controllers are not connected by a segue.

I hope this is clear. I just want to know the syntax in the first UIViewController to assign the value to another UIViewController property like NSString. I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Are you using StoryBoard and want to pass data through segue? If yes, there are plenty of this kind of questions and plenty of answers...

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, the two controllers are NOT connected by a segue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have the SecondViewController be a property of the FirstViewController.  That way FirstViewController can reference it.

EDITED to answer question in comment

**Property Example:**

```
@interface FirstViewController()
property (strong, nonatomic) SecondViewController *secondViewController;
@end

@implementation FirstViewController

-(id)init
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)didPressBanana
{
    [self.secondViewController bananaWasPressed];

    // OR

    self.secondViewController.fruit = @"banana";
}

@end
```

SecondViewController.h

```
@interface SecondViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *fruit;

@end
```

**OR**

SecondViewController.m

```
-(void)bananaWasPressed
{
    self.fruit = @"banana";
}
```

---

Or alternatively you can use protocols if you want the to go the other way and have the SecondViewController communicate back to the FirstViewController.

**Protocol Example:**

SecondViewController.h

```
@protocol SecondViewControllerDelegate
-(void)didPressBanana;
@end

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController
    @property (nonatomic, unsafe_unretained) id<SecondViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

SecondViewController.m

```
-(void)didPressBanana 
{
    [self.delegate didPressBanana];
}
```

FirstViewController.m

```
@interface FirstViewController()
@property (nonatomic, strong) SecondViewController *secondViewController;
@end

@implementation FirstViewController <SecondViewControllerDelegate>

-(id)init
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self.secondViewController setDelegate:self];
}

// delegate method conforms to SecondViewControllerDelegate protocol
-(void)didPressBanana
{
    // do something 
}

@end
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. This looks like great code, but just a quick clarification: in the property example, can the first view controller assign a value to a property in the second view controller? So, if the second view controller has a "Fruit" NSString, can the first view controller then assign "Banana" to that NSString? And more importantly, if the user opens up the second view controller, will it have the banana as its Fruit NSString?

Comment: Sorry for the long question, I just want to make sure I'm doing this right :)

Comment: Yes, if the Fruit property is defined in .h file of SecondViewController or you can do the assignment in the SecondViewController's bananaWasPressed method.  I will update my post to reflect this functionality.

Comment: I've added code in my post to address this behavior.  Also for your question "if the user opens up the second view controller, will it have the banana as its Fruit NSString?": YES!

Answer (score 0):

If the first UIViewController doesn't have the reference to the second UIViewController then you can use a singleton model object that is updated by the first UIViewController and read by the second UIViewController. Here is a good reference for creating a singleton: http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/11/singletons-appdelegates-and-top-level.html

Answer (score 0):

Either make `secondViewController` as a Parent View Controller of `FirstViewController`, in that case you can access all the properties of parent View Controller or Use `NSNotificationCenter` to send notification from First View Contrlller to Second.

**ParentViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ParentViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *mytextView;

@end
```

**ChildViewController.h**

```
#import "ParentViewController.h"

@interface ChildViewController : ParentViewController

@end
```

**ChildViewController.m**

```
#import "ChildViewController.h"

@interface ChildViewController ()

@end

@implementation ChildViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.mytextView = @"Value";
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot make the set-up of this particular project of mine so that one of the classes a parent of the other. However, I appreciate the thoughtful response. Thank you!