# Passing data between UIViewController and UITableViewController not connected via segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitableview, segue

I followed the advice at this link [Changing the value of a property of another UIViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17356543/changing-the-value-of-a-property-of-another-uiviewcontroller)

I have a Login page that is connected to a github project that I downloaded called [SWRevealViewController](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController). It essentially provides a slide out menu for the application. I need to pass a value from my Login Page to the initial Page that is loaded with the SWRevealViewController. Can't seem to get it working. Can anyone point me in the right direction? What I have tried is the following:

LoginViewController.m

```
#import "LoginViewController.h"
#import "ProfileTableViewController.h"

@interface LoginViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) ProfileTableViewController *secondViewController;
@end

@implementation dbViewController

-(id)init
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.secondViewController = [[ProfileTableViewController alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

- (BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender{


    if([identifier isEqualToString:@"Login"]){
        [self login:sender];
        self.secondViewController.idNumber = _IDNumber;
        _secondViewController.idNumber = _IDNumber;            
            return YES;
     }    
}
```

LoginViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <sqlite3.h>
#import "ProfileTableViewController.h"

@interface LoginViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic)NSString *IDNumber;
@end
```

ProfileTableViewController.h

```
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <sqlite3.h>

@interface ProfileTableViewController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate>
@property (nonatomic) NSString *idNumber;
@end
```

ProfileTableViewController.m

```
#import "ProfileTableViewController.h"
#import "SWRevealViewController.h"
#import "ProfileEditFieldController.h"

@interface ProfileTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation ProfileTableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(_idNumber);

}
@end
```

Just to add clarification, the two blue controllers are the Login, and the three controllers on the right, one of them is the controller I would like to pass the value for
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do it like this instead:

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
        ProfileTableViewController *pvc = (ProfileTableViewController*)[segue destinationViewController];
        pvc.idNumber = _IDNumber

}
```

Hope that works! :)

UPDATE:

I think what you need is NSUserDefaults, use it, and store the ID. You gonna need it in more than one controller I believe, and its easy to store data on.

[NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSUserDefaults/standardUserDefaults)

Comment: The two controllers are not connected directly via segue though?

Comment: They should be connected from the storyboard, and this code should be in the LogInViewController. You don't initialize it from your code, you just get the initialized one from the storyboard. Try it and let me know if it works :)

Comment: I'm not sure have I explained this correctly, so I added in a screenshot of the storyboard to better explain it.

Answer (score 1):

It's not 100% clear from what you've shown but I'm assuming that these view controllers are defined in a storyboard and that the "Login" segue is also defined in the storyboard and causes a transition from LoginViewController to ProfileTableViewController.

One thing I am confused about is why the @implementation line in LoginViewController.m says "dbViewController" but I'm assuming that's a typo and that it should be "@implementation LoginViewController".

So, assuming all of that is true, there are a couple of problems in your code. First, you shouldn't be creating the ProfileTableViewController in LoginViewController's init method. iOS will automatically alloc and init the ProfileTableViewController when the segue is performed.

Second, instead of using shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:sender:, you want to use prepareForSegue:sender:. When that method is called, iOS will have already created the ProfileTableViewController and you can set your property.

So, what you want is something like:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Login"])
    {
        ProfileTableViewController * viewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        viewController.idNumber = _IDNumber;
    }
}
```

Comment: Mr_bern answered while I was typing but, yes, his answer is correct.